# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string

Tags: image, laravel, file-upload

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'product.store', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

i'm using this code but it generate the following error

**FatalThrowableError**

**Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $formInput = $request->except('image');

    $image = $request->image;            

    if($image){
        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move('images',$imageName);
        $formInput['image'] = $imageName;
    }

    Product::create($formInput);
    return redirect()->route('admin.index');
}
```

Comment: What's the result of `dd($image)`?

Comment: need to use `file()` method. `$request->file('image')`

Answer (score 0):

use file() if you want to get file extension

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $formInput = $request->except('image');        

    if($image){
        $ext  = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move('images',$imageName);
        $formInput['image'] = $imageName;
    }

    Product::create($formInput);
    return redirect()->route('admin.index');
}
```